# chef node is not executing the chef-client command

Tags: ubuntu, installation, chef-infra, instances

I have created two aws ubuntu instances. One will be worked as a workstation and another as a node. I have bootstrapped the node and it is working fine. When I type `knife node list` it shows the node which I have created.

After creating recipe apache, whenever I try to execute `sudo chef-client` on the node, it throws an error. I am not able to rectify. This is the error:

[image]

Comment: Is this a custom cookbook or a community cookbook ? (if it's a custom one, change httpd by apache2 in your recipe, if i's a community one, change, it is not compatible with ubuntu, try the apache2 cookbook)

Comment: (Just in case: the error would be the same just running `apt-get install httpd` on command line out of chef, this is not a chef error on itself)

Comment: Thankyou Brother!! it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

`httpd` is the package name on RHEL-style systems. On Debian-style systems the package name is `apache2`. The learnchef tutorial doesn't make this super clear.